# Postgresql: select string without given substring

Tags: postgresql

I have three columns:

```
Name           | Number  | Number2
abc $18 12mb   | $18     | 12mb
10mb 1cd $19   | $19     | 10mb
$15 30mb ab123 | $15     | 30mb
```

I want to create column: new_name as name without number and number2. Any ideas?

Expected output:

```
Name      | Number  | Number2
abc       | $18     | 12mb
1cd       | $19     | 10mb
ab123     | $15     | 30mb
```

Answer (score 2):

One method uses `replace()`:

```
select trim(both ' ' from replace(name, Number, ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just nest your replace statements. Simple way:

```
alter table mytable add new_name text;

update mytable set new_name =     
trim(both ' ' from replace(replace("name", "Number", ''),"Number2", ''))
```

Note that this won't work for cases where either column is null. Hanlde nulls with coalesce():

```
update mytable set new_name =     
    trim(both ' ' from replace(replace("name", coalesce("Number",''), ''),coalesce("Number2",''), ''))
```

This will still fail if Number is a substring of Number2, because the inner replace will replace that bit of the Number2 part and the outer replace won't do anything. You can do a more complicated way that should work in all cases:

```
-- replace the longer string first
 update mytable set new_name =     
 CASE WHEN coalesece(length("Number"),0) > coalesce(length("Number2"),0) THEN 
    trim(both ' ' from replace(replace("name", coalesce("Number",''), ''),coalesce("Number2",''), ''))
 ELSE
    trim(both ' ' from replace(replace("name", coalesce("Number2",''), ''),coalesce("Number",''), ''))
END
```

For the case where the numbers are the same length (and identical) this will work, because the inner replace will do what you want.

Comment: Ok thanks! what if for one Name Number is only filled (without number2)? If trim(both ' ' from replace(replace(name, "Number", ''),"Number2", '')) it returns blank.